# android : OWA apis for android to connect to exchange mail server

Tags: android, outlook-web-app

I want to know if there any OWA library / apis that can be used in my android app to connect to exchange server and send / receive mails

Answer (score 0):

Davmail server can be used to translate OWA calls to standard ones: http://davmail.sourceforge.net/

> The main goal of DavMail is to provide standard compliant protocols in front of proprietary Exchange. This means LDAP for global address book, SMTP to send messages, IMAP to browse messages on the server in any folder, POP to retrieve inbox messages only, Caldav for calendar support and Carddav for personal contacts sync. Thus any standard compliant client can be used with Microsoft Exchange.